# Check for efficiency: Opengl Animation code

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I made a little chunk of code for doing opengl animations for Ludum dare.  It works fine but im just wondering if it is efficient enough for me to consider reusing it for more important games in the future.  I am mostly conserned about the fact that I'm casting multiple integers to floats every update, and if I remember correctly casted objects are stored in memory until the program is terminated (please correct me if I'm wrong).
I am aware I am using outdated OpenGl, but new Opengl seems very hard to learn.  If there is some easy way to do this efficiently with new openGL please feel free let me know.  If there is any other way I can improve this code to make it more efficient please respond with your suggested improvements.

```
   public class AnimatedObject {
private int frames;
private int currentframe;
private int tex;

public void update(){
if (currentframe<frames){

currentframe = currentframe +1;
}
else{
    currentframe = 1;
}
 GL11.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        System.out.println(currentframe);
        System.out.println("total frames"+frames);
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        //GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprites);
        float bob = (float)currentframe/frames;
        float bop = (float)(currentframe-1)/frames;
        System.out.println(bob);
        System.out.println(bop+ "is bop");
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
          GL11.glTexCoord2f(bop, 0);
            GL11.glVertex2i(-1, 1); // Upper-left
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(bob, 0);
            GL11.glVertex2i(1, 1); // Upper-right
            GL11. glTexCoord2f(bob, 1);
            GL11.glVertex2i(1, -1); // Bottom-right
            GL11. glTexCoord2f(bop, 1);
            GL11.glVertex2i(-1, -1); // Bottom-left


            GL11.glPopMatrix();
        GL11.glEnd();

     }
    public AnimatedObject(int frames, int tex){
    this.frames = frames;
    this.tex= tex;

}

}
```

Comment: Questions like this might be better on [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think conversions between integer and floats are the least of your issues. Using immediate mode GL will kill all performance and costs thousands of cpu cycles here. Even if you stick to legacy GL with fixed-function pipeline, there are better options like vertex arrays and VBOs. Ulitimately, your goal should be increasing batch sizes and coalescing as much as possible into a single draw call.